# What does $\rho_k = 0$ mean?

Tags: statistics, time-series

I'm reading [Introductory Time Series with R](https://www.springer.com/gb/book/9780387886978) in a section where the correlogram is discussed.

I'm confused by one of the statements:

> If $\rho_k = 0$, the sampling distribution of $r_k$ is approximately normal, with a mean of $-1/n$ and a variance of $1/n$.

Earlier in the book the following are defined:

$$\rho_k = \frac{\gamma_k}{\sigma^2}$$

$$\gamma_k = E[(x_t - \mu)(x_{t+k} - \mu)]$$

My confusion is what $\rho_k = 0$ means.  Should I read this as:

- all the values of $\rho$ for each '$t$ and $t+k$' pair are zero? Or,
- the sum of all values of $\rho$ for each '$t$ and $t+k$' pair are zero? Or,
- something else?

I think the first one is correct. I.e. $\rho_1 = 0, \rho_2 = 0, ..., \rho_n = 0$

Simple answers preferred over complex ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under the null hypothesis there is no auto-correlation of order $k$ in the series, i.e., $\rho_k = 0$.

Comment: Ah, I get it now, there is no auto-correlation if the correlation is zero for *each* value of k.